# UserWarning: WARN: Box bound precision lowered by casting to float32

Tags: python, python-3.x

I continuously get this error

```
UserWarning: WARN: Box bound precision lowered by casting to float32
  warnings.warn(colorize('%s: %s'%('WARN', msg % args), 'yellow'))
```

when I start my training session. I guess it's coming from this line

```
self.action_space = spaces.Box(low, high)
```

The code is running but I want to stop this error from showing up

I am using a cuda pc to run the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Explicitly specify the `dtype` as `float32` in the call like so...

```
self.action_space = spaces.Box(low, high, dtype=np.float32)
```

If that doesn't work, set the logger level lower in gym like so...

```
import gym
gym.logger.set_level(40)
```

Comment: Specifying the dtype as float32 will not solve the problem, since the original warning complains about the fact that float32 is being used. Setting it to ```dtype=np.float64``` will make the warning go away.

Answer (score 15):

Just cast the dtype *of the values* you pass `Box` to `float32`:

`self.action_space = spaces.Box(np.float32(low), np.float32(high))`

For example, also all these examples are valid:

`self.action_space = spaces.Box(np.float32(3), np.float32(4.0))`

`self.action_space = spaces.Box(np.float32(np.array([3.0,3.5])), np.float32(np.array([4.0,4.5])))`

`self.action_space = spaces.Box(np.array([3.0,3.5],dtype=np.float32), np.array([4.0,4.5],dtype=np.float32))`

By the way: While you can also explicitly cast the `Box`-`dtype` itself to `np.float32` as @Robert Wilkerson suggests, there is no need for it: it does not solve the problem, and it has no effect as the `dtype` of `Box` already defaults to `np.float32`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. `space.Box(a,b,dtype=np.float32)` will give the warning if `a` or `b` are not of type float32 (e.g. if they are default python float64). The default dtype for Box is float32, in OP low and high are probably of type float64.

Comment: Not only does this work, but the accepted answer also does NOT work.